# Is it possible to add a constraint in SQL Server 2012 to prevent new data from being entered until old data is soft deleted?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [DeletedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NULL,

    UNIQUE([Name], [DeletedOn]),

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);

GO
```

I insert a new record like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Test] (Name, DeletedOn) VALUES ('A record', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

Subsequent inserts with this command will complete as expected. However, I want to require that before data with a `DeletedOn` value newer than an existing record with the same `Name` be rejected so long as a record with the same `Name` exists in the table with a `NULL` `DeletedOn` value.

A different way to explain this behavior would be to have you imagine a user password history. Users enter in passwords and my software hashes them and stores it in the database. A user's password expires and `DeletedOn` is set to the current date and time. I never want users to enter the same password over again, so that is the purpose for keeping the history. In order to maintain data consistency, I want to prevent a password from being added when there is already an active one that does not have a value in the `DeletedOn` column. So, if my software erroneously behaves and tries to add random passwords to a user's password history, it should fail because it would violate some constraint that prevents deletion of passwords that are not the single active password.

I originally imagined I would just wrap this logic in a stored procedure and throw an error up if such behavior was attempted, but I am curious if this could be done in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge There is no out of box feature to prevent new data from being     entered until old data is soft deleted? We need to add some CONSTRAINT to prevent that. We can use check constraint and validate whether the combination of Name and Deleted On exists or not.

Try This

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[chk_RecordExists](@Name Varchar(255))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result int
SET @Result = 0

DECLARE @id AS INT
SET @id=0
SELECT @id=MAX(ID) FROM [Test] WHERE Name = @Name

IF (@id=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1 -- Allow to insert as its New record
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
-- Check the latest record for name if Deletedon is not null then its soft deleted can allow to insert new 
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM [Test] WHERE ID=@id AND Name = @Name AND DeletedOn IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1  -- Allow to insert as its old data is soft deleted
    END 
END

RETURN @Result
END
GO

ALTER TABLE Test WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_Constraint]     CHECK(dbo.chk_RecordExists](Name)=0)

GO
```

Comment: This is very simple and maintains data integrity checks at the lowest possible level. I never knew you could define complicated checks inside functions.

Comment: @MitchWheat So, this is the second comment I've seen on one of my questions from you, with little explanation. Can you elaborate on how this is broken? I admit, I rewrote this implementation to work for me and never tested the original. However, the concept is pretty solid it seems. What is your thought on it?

Comment: The comment is on an answer. The fact it is an answer to one of your questions is coincidence. There is no transaction around selecting the MAX and subsequent use of it when it could have changed. This probably should not be an accepted answer, as it might lead people astray.

Comment: @MitchWheat Aren't constraint checks done at the equivalent of a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction level to enforce the ACID principle? An `INSERT` is considered a statement and all statements are transactions and all transactions are atomic operations.

Comment: That's not what I was referring to.  Select max value from a table with active inserts. Sometime later select max from table, Is it the same value?

Comment: @MitchWheat It may or may not be. But, SQL Server will add exclusive key locks during inserts and when `SELECT MAX(SomeColumn)` attempts to get a shared lock it will be put into a waiting state, regardless of preemption by statements inside different transactions. So it's still safe as far as I can tell. Do you have a test case that shows the problem? I'm interested still.

Answer (score 0):

I have never user `INSTEAD OF` keywords but I have read that it can be used to do exactly what you want. Below is sample code from MSDN to prevent insert of new record if there is old record. Full afticle on `INSTEAD OF` [can be found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_INS_Employee ON Employee
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Check for duplicate Person. If there is no duplicate, do an insert.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.SSN
      FROM Person P, inserted I
      WHERE P.SSN = I.SSN))
   INSERT INTO Person
      SELECT SSN,Name,Address,Birthdate
      FROM inserted
ELSE
-- Log an attempt to insert duplicate Person row in PersonDuplicates table.
   INSERT INTO PersonDuplicates
      SELECT SSN,Name,Address,Birthdate,SUSER_SNAME(),GETDATE()
      FROM inserted
-- Check for duplicate Employee. If no there is duplicate, do an INSERT.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT E.SSN
      FROM EmployeeTable E, inserted
      WHERE E.SSN = inserted.SSN))
   INSERT INTO EmployeeTable
      SELECT EmployeeID,SSN, Department, Salary
      FROM inserted
ELSE
--If there is a duplicate, change to UPDATE so that there will not
--be a duplicate key violation error.
   UPDATE EmployeeTable
      SET EmployeeID = I.EmployeeID,
          Department = I.Department,
          Salary = I.Salary
   FROM EmployeeTable E, inserted I
   WHERE E.SSN = I.SSN
END
```

Changes to trigger above to only insert unique rows

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_INS_TEST ON MyTestTable
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON            

        IF (
             NOT EXISTS ( SELECT P.SSN
                            FROM MyTestTable P
                               ,inserted I
                            WHERE P.SSN = I.SSN ) )
            INSERT INTO MyTestTable
                    SELECT FirstName
                           ,LastName
                           ,SSN
                        FROM ( SELECT FirstName
                                   ,LastName
                                   ,SSN
                                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SSN ORDER BY LastName, Firstname ) AS ROWNUM
                                FROM INSERTED ) A
                        WHERE A.ROWNUM = 1
        ELSE
            RAISERROR(N'You are trying to insert duplicate records',16,1)
    END
```

Comment: It's a shame that that trigger is broken. It avoids the usual prat-falls (i.e. many people write broken triggers that assume `inserted` only contains a single row) but then trips over by not checking whether `inserted`, itself, contains duplicate values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have modified my answer to include trigger that will only insert unique values